# Vertical navbar hover effect

Tags: html, css, reactjs, hover, navbar

how can i do such hover effect on vertical navbar?
[image]

I couldn't find any information,if you know where i can read about that,give me a link please!

**Code:**

```
//imagine it is html with classes (.LogosContainer,.Logo)
<LogosContainer>
  <Logo src={iconHome} alt="home" />
  <Logo src={iconGlobe} alt="globe" />
  <Logo src={iconArchive} alt="archive" />
  <Logo src={iconPieChart} alt="pie-chart" />
  <Logo src={iconDollarSign} alt="dollar" />
  <Logo src={iconDatabase} alt="database" />
  <Logo src={iconNavigation} alt="navigation" />
</LogosContainer>
```

```css
const Logo = styled.img`
  margin-bottom: 43px;

  &:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
`;

    const LogosContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;
```

Comment: Hi:) What is the hover effect actually? The left white border?

Comment: @Azu hello,yes!

Comment: Could you please share the code of Logo component?

Comment: @Azu i had it in my question,see above.<Logo/> it is a styled component,simple <img/>

Answer (score 0):

In styles file add:

```
/**color of your choice on hovering*/
Logo:hover{
     background-color: yellow;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have an image, I've used a div here. As I don't know how to work with styled components, I leave it to you to use the styles I provide:

```css
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: red;          
}
.container:hover {
    border-left: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```